# Right place to save images (spring/jelastic)

Tags: java, spring, jelastic

I'm truing to implement user profile functionality, at the firts I've found an example for upploading photos, and it saves it to the app folder, like `home\jelastic\app\my_folder` but there is an 2 issues:

1) if i need to update an app and upload new build i want to save this images, but i lose this data

2) i'm not able to read the photos (input stream is null by some reason)

```
public @ResponseBody byte[] getImageWithMediaType() throws IOException {
        InputStream in = getClass()
                .getResourceAsStream(storageService.getPath() + "/1544717586066.jpeg");
        return ByteStreams.toByteArray(in);
    }
```

so, what is the right way to save/read photos on jelastic?

Comment: I would store it in a database as a blob

Comment: thank you. i've thinked about this, but looks the better way is to use file storage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: ok follow that advice - and use a database to store the metadata for the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you take a look at [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  This is designed to do exactly what you are trying to do.

Assuming you are using Spring Data to store each user profile you might add it to your project as follows:

> pom.xml

```
   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-fs-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

> FilesystemConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class FilesystemConfiguration {

    @Bean
    File filesystemRoot() {
        try {
            return new File("/path/to/your/user/profile/image/store");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {}
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(filesystemRoot().getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

> User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   ...other existing fields...

   @ContentId
   private String contentId;

   @ContentLength
   private long contentLength = 0L;

   @MimeType
   private String mimeType = "text/plain";

   ...
}
```

> UserContentStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="userProfileImages")
public interface UserContentStore extends ContentStore<User, String> {
}
```

This is all you need to do to get REST Endpoints that will allow you to store and retrieve content associated with each User.  How this actually works is very much like Spring Data.  When your application starts Spring Content will see the `spring-content-fs-boot-starter` dependencies and know that you want to store content on the filesystem.  It will also inject a Filesystem-based implementation of the `UserContentStore` interface.  It will also see the `spring-content-rest-boot-starter` and will inject REST endpoints that talk to the content store interface.  Meaning you don't have to write any of this code yourself.

So, for example:

`curl -X POST /userProfileImages/{userId} -F "file=@/path/to/image.jpg"`

will store the image on the filesystem and associate it with the user entity whose id is `userId`.

`curl /userProfileImages/{userId}`

will fetch it again and so on...supports full CRUD and video streaming too actually.

You could also decide to store the contents elsewhere like in the database (as someone commented), or in S3 by swapping the `spring-content-fs-boot-starter` dependency for the appropriate Spring Content Storage module.  Examples for every type of storage are [here](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content-examples).